# Check in EL if array contains specific element

Tags: jsp, el

Is there is any way to check if expected element is present in array in EL? I don't see any other way other than iterate the whole array and see if value matches the expected one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Framework, you can use Spring TagLib + SpEL and common-lang3:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
---
<spring:eval var="containsValue" expression="T(org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils).contains(yourArray, 'expectedElement')" />
Contains (true or false): ${containsValue}
```